# Symfony findBy DATEDIFF

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get all the entries that are having a date bigger than 4 weeks like this

```
$oRepoArticleImage->findBy(array('deletedAt' => 'DATEDIFF(now(), deletedAt) > 4'));
```

I am getting the following error. What I am doing wrong?

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object
>   in
>   .../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php
>   on line 53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find by always expects a key-value array. In your case you are trying to use a string as a DateTime object. This does not work. To get the expected result, you have to use an query builder like this:

```
     $now = new \DateTime();
    // four weeks in days (28)
    $daysAgo = $now->sub(new \DateInterval('P28D'));
    $images = $oRepoArticleImage->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->where('i.deletedAt < :date')
        ->setParameter('date', $daysAgo)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: That should do it! Thanks!

Comment: `P4W` also works, even though it gets converted into days it lets the code "speak for itself" so to say. The `new DateTime()` may also need to be `new \DateTime()`

Comment: The php docs say that W (weeks) get converted into days, therefore I would prefer days instead of weeks.

Comment: Sure - my comment about that is only an opinion. Though... you could also use relative time with `new \DateTime('4 weeks ago')` or `new \DateTime('28 days ago')` and avoid using `DateTime::sub()` entirely.